# Does Zurich ETH provide campus acommodation for Postdocs?

Tags: postdocs, university, switzerland

and how good it is? is it shared or private? Subsidized, paid or for free? and if paid, how does it compete against living outside campus?

Comment: Consider asking your PI / Department this question, it's very likely they know exactly what their own policies are.

Comment: The housing office is at https://www.wohnen.ethz.ch/en